# Как изменить ответ валидатора в Laravel?

Tags: json, laravel, валидация

Я пишу api для своего приложения. Решил вынести всю валидацию в отдельные request, как рекомендуется в документации по Laravel 8. Но мне мне непонятно как я могу кастомизировать ответ в случае валидационной ошибки, так как мой клиент ожидает ответ в виде json с ключем status: false.

Вот мой контроллер

```
public function store(StoreChatroomRequest $request)
{
    $request_data = $request->validated();

    ...
}
```

Вот StoreChatroomRequest

```
public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'title.required' => 'Поле title является обязательным',
            'sender_id.required' => 'Поле sender_id является обязательным',
            'receiver_id.required' => 'Поле receiver_id является обязательным'
        ];
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'title' => 'required|string|min:1',
            'sender_id' => 'required|integer',
            'receiver_id' => 'required|integer'
        ];
    }
```

Когда я получаю валидационную ошибку, то в ответ о тсервера приходит следующий JSON

```
{
    "message": "The given data was invalid.",
    "errors": {
        "title": [
            "Поле title является обязательным"
        ],
        "sender_id": [
            "Поле sender_id является обязательным"
        ],
        "receiver_id": [
            "Поле receiver_id является обязательным"
        ]
    }
}
```

Однако, я хотел бы видеть что-то вроде такого

```
{
    "status": true,
    "errors": {
         ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Смотрите [after validation hook](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#after-validation-hook) и отдавайте свой нужный формат через response()->json().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

можно переопредилить метод `failedValidation(Validator $validator)` в классе `StoreChatroomRequest` и сформировать там exception с нужной структурой

Answer (score 4):

В файле `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` Вы можете переопределить следующие функции для того, чтобы ответы применялись к любому запросу (как валидация, так и исключения):

```
// В шапку
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;
use Throwable;

public function convertValidationExceptionToResponse(ValidationException $e, $request)
{
    if($e instanceof ValidationException && $request->expectsJson()) {
        return response()->json([
            "status" => false,
            "messages" => ['You have errors in form'],
            "errors" =>  $e->errors()
        ], 422);
    } else {
        parent::convertValidationExceptionToResponse($e, $request);
    }
}


public function convertExceptionToArray(Throwable $e)
{
    return config('app.debug') ? [
        'status' => false,
        'messages' => [$e->getMessage()],
        'exception' => get_class($e),
        'file' => $e->getFile(),
        'line' => $e->getLine(),
        'trace' => collect($e->getTrace())->map(function ($trace) {
            return Arr::except($trace, ['args']);
        })->all(),
    ] : [
        'status' => false,
        'messages' => [$e->getMessage()],
    ];
}
```